# Множество целых чисел Java

Tags: ооп, java

Доброе время суток!

Задали мне такое домашнее задание: есть класс `OMOSet`,который репрезентует множество целых чисел. Надо написать методы `add(int element)`,`remove(int element)`. Так дан исходный код, в который надо дописать методы. Вопрос: т.к. класс `OMOSet` уже является множеством, то нельзя использовать `AttayList`, `Collection`... Надо написать конструктор и атрибуты? Как создать множество вручную?

```
class OMOSet implements OMOSetView {
  public void add(int element) {
  }
  public void remove(int element) {
  }
}
```

Comment: @evgeniya, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала необходимо определить структуру хранения данных. Учитывая, что множество не ограничено, то статическая структура в виде сырого массива не подойдет. Классы Java Collection использовать нельзя, потому придется велосипедить. Тут уже только твоя воля: динамический массив (надстройка над сырым массивом), список, бинарное дерево, хэш-таблица или еще что-то. Что конкретно выбрать - это зависит от требований по сложности доступа, вставки (в конец, начало, середину, с сортировкой или без).

Вдохновляться советую уже существующим:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Интерфейс Set реализуют основные классы-множества:

- HashSet (на основе хэш-таблицы)
- LinkedHashSet (на основе связного списка и хэш-таблицы ссылок),
- TreeSet (на основе сбалансированного бинарного дерева)

С динамическим массивом и на основе простого связного списка - самые простые реализации, но ее не используют, т.к. в множествах, как правило, не нужна индексация (массив), косвенный доступ и прямой перебор (как в массиве, так и в списке) стоит операций.

Answer (score 0):

Может есть смысл в качестве поля указать массив интов (int[] set)и с ним работать:  
 - add: создаешь новый массив, кладешь в него новый элемент и говоришь, что ссылка set теперь ссылается на этот новый удлиненный массив  
 - remove: создается массив длинно на единицу меньше текущего и в него копируются все элементы из set, которые != element. Дальше просто говоришь, что ссылка set теперь ссылается на этот укороченный массивчик

Comment: Спасибо.А как в таком случае создать конструктор?

Comment: а что нужно?

Comment: Я Вас поняла,спасибо еще раз. Я только начинаю программировать и показалось странным,что у класса нет никаких атрибутов

Comment: Нормально, первые шаги всегда такие..   Я вот только что-то про отсутствие атрибутов не понял - Вы про что?

Comment: @Stas0n видимо под атрибутами подразумеваются поля

Comment: да,я имела ввиду поле.